# What setting is causing VS Code to mess up code formatting when I paste?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on vue file, but same problem happens when in javascript language mode.

When I paste in the following text,

```html
<li><a 
    :class="{'toggle':true, 'layerOn':dispHandicappedParking}" 
    href="#"
    @click.prevent="dispHandicappedParking =! dispHandicappedParking"
    >Accessible Parking</a>
</li>
```

VS Code immediately autoformats it to the following:

```html
    < li > <a 
                            : class="{'toggle':true, 'layerOn':dispHandicappedParking}"
href = "#"
@click.prevent="dispHandicappedParking =! dispHandicappedParking"
    > Accessible Parking < /a>
        < /li>
```

If I then hit "undo", the bad formatting is removed, but the pasted code stays (which in itself seems a strange behavior: I'd expect paste to be a one-step-undoable action).

What setting to I need to adjust in order to stop the editor from mangling my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, was an extension: [Vue Language Features](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.vue-language-features-insiders). I guess that's what I get for installing a preview build and forgetting about it!